# A class for show image in square

Tags: android

I see a class that use this class for show images in square.

i can't understand what is this class? have any feature for show images in square?

this code used in layout xml file instead of RelativeLayout

```
class SquareLayout extends RelativeLayout {

public SquareLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // Set a square layout.
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: `onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec)`... It's a square... What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The important line is `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);`. As you can see, the height is replace with the width. So you have `width x width` instead of `width x height`. That is a square. `onMeasure` is used to tell the system the requested Area of the view. Hope it helps